# How to root htc desire 626s metro pcs

Tags: rooting, htc-desire

How can i root HTC desire 626s metro PC phone? Tried many ways. Cannot seem to find a way to turn s-off and edit code.

Comment: Which method have you tried, have you try any app ??  I probably Suggest Root Genius for PC for Rooting purpose. Try this : http://rootgenius.com/

Comment: Any way you can give some details on what you actually did? Would help a lot. Thanks

Comment: How to Root HTC Desire 626s.and without pc
http://www.themobileupdates.com/how-to/how-to-root-htc-desire-626s/

Answer (score 1):

It didn't solve it however once I realized that HTC calls their backup a ruu file I was able to alter the common push su code and able to use lost Android to exploit the temp root and change the build props to turn s-off